Web Scraping Manchester City website using BS4 and python
So basically, I wanted to extract all the texts from the https://www.mancity.com/fixtures website regarding the dates of the upcoming matchs and put it into a list.
The issue is, im unable to extract anything when I give the class name of the div tag and to extract all the data, it just returns an empty list
It may be an error from my side, but after a lot of troubleshooting I am still unable to solve it :(
Please Help..
The Code :
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.mancity.com/fixtures'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
dates_tag = soup.find_all("div", class_="fixture-header__competition")
dates = []

for date in dates_tag:
    dates.append(date)

print(dates)

The Output :
[]

The Versions:
requests==2.32.3
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3

It's a dynamic page. Save response.content to an html file and inspect it with browser; if the content you look for is not there then bs will not find anything. https://www.zenrows.com/blog/scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages#prerequisites

Cloudflare protects your target app (you will see 403 Forbidden Error if you try response.status_code and there is no bypass working (on my end, I tried cookie and user-agent), so the only option is left to use Selenium with bs4,
here is the code with the Selenium chrome driver with bs4,
Sample code:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.mancity.com/fixtures')

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find_all("li", class_="grid grid-bleed fixture fixtures-list-item")
for i in content:
    match = i['aria-label']
    time = i.find('time')['datetime']
    print(f"Match: {match} | Time: {time}")

Edit:
Sample code with the https://proxyium.com/ proxy:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://95.214.53.28/fixtures?__cpo=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubWFuY2l0eS5jb20'

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:132.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/132.0",
    "Cookie": "__cpc=UzhHa3hFSnZDQ1gxR01MRDlDWVUxWHBjQ3JWclpmQXFZeis5L0x2bHhQV0hYUzdJWWVwaEhqVXVLbEM0NHRsZUp4aGFuTFlrald2TE0zNlk1Sm05OWVTTG1nM3Q5MG9mZU52TnZQZ1Y3ZFZ0ZHZJN1ZFWkQ2clBBNHIzZVJTRG41ZjNrWjI0Wld1emZoelg5M1F6ak9yRGd5ZjZjYzlIVVZSMTRxQkJBZXQ4PQ==; __cpcPopShown=1; LocationInfo@mancity.com=PL,95.214.53.28,Europe/Warsaw; __cf_bm@mancity.com=sMqolpEOCnoXdUmwpSuoY8bI9XV9tx5uNsDNitUDLaE-1732867533-1.0.1.1-tBlrXm2RvG4PZJXekOnQo6vXsaZ.dXGwjvDxpF2rLqKCO91ePn0KXohmlcLyW418LR7pyDv12WXM35snQOkL0Q; ARRAffinity@www.mancity.com=3aa7a79f9efc4dbf0ff47ee910aeb51c25cad2a6b2ab0d01e787a809841db575; ARRAffinitySameSite@www.mancity.com=3aa7a79f9efc4dbf0ff47ee910aeb51c25cad2a6b2ab0d01e787a809841db575; ai_user@www.mancity.com=xXd5XC4W9G6kMPUhATgMov|2024-11-29T08:05:43.287Z; __cpcStatSampleNum=2; ai_session@www.mancity.com=R899bnC48HIvLzEqXYQQUO|1732867544016|1732867547991; cf_clearance@mancity.com=wNaD6_MC7nB7dXFUmcC3nhkBcdEahUO7tdnHJp46JCM-1732867543-1.2.1.1-BsYgil1dxKqc0xZC4ovvXSKVoLuqcSURqTb4wtHdWDtQQlHBHG._STMECcRaBJfCWcO94lV8KR4WCsNT8RXteWkrhrymq4dTPrAp66dPzZuVYvitBaHV.HECGjgViWoFDjnDHEkJTVH5fOVbqWJBwCvsJ.iUGgv1OccYaSW78zs05kduaPCG4Q9McUql4oZrmr9UVDj_HbmuMuKbvclFW3MTmhh.hVOlWRqe.LfYpZWhtHkvpFJsuqbJKgm5joOeBSmmNMHwlzuO_pOZibwfeDAuojUNyvZZwP8mnUsjHC98Q69D45UkBDOKy7Vw5vDI27UbxQ_0jPop3jAQzVonng; OptanonConsent@mancity.com=isGpcEnabled=0&datestamp=Fri+Nov+29+2024+14%3A06%3A06+GMT%2B0600+(Bangladesh+Standard+Time)&version=202403.1.0&browserGpcFlag=0&isIABGlobal=false&hosts=&consentId=7846314b-9fdc-4b05-8dce-6749d219d03d&interactionCount=2&isAnonUser=1&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0005%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0004%3A1; OptanonAlertBoxClosed@mancity.com=2024-11-29T08:06:06.324Z"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=header).text, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find_all("li", class_="grid grid-bleed fixture fixtures-list-item")
for i in content:
    match = i['aria-label']
    time = i.find('time')['datetime']
    print(f"Match: {match} | Time: {time}")

Output:
Match: Liverpool versus Manchester City | Time: 2024-12-01T16:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Manchester City versus Nottingham Forest | Time: 2024-12-04T19:30:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Crystal Palace versus Manchester City | Time: 2024-12-07T15:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Juventus versus Manchester City | Time: 2024-12-11T20:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Manchester City versus Manchester United | Time: 2024-12-15T16:30:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Aston Villa versus Manchester City | Time: 2024-12-21T12:30:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Manchester City versus Everton | Time: 2024-12-26T12:30:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Leicester City versus Manchester City | Time: 2024-12-29T14:30:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Manchester City versus West Ham United | Time: 2025-01-04T15:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Brentford versus Manchester City | Time: 2025-01-14T19:30:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Ipswich Town versus Manchester City | Time: 2025-01-19T16:30:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Paris Saint-Germain versus Manchester City | Time: 2025-01-22T20:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Manchester City versus Chelsea | Time: 2025-01-25T17:30:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Manchester City versus Club Brugge | Time: 2025-01-29T20:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Arsenal versus Manchester City | Time: 2025-02-01T15:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Manchester City versus Newcastle United | Time: 2025-02-15T15:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Manchester City versus Liverpool | Time: 2025-02-22T15:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Tottenham Hotspur versus Manchester City | Time: 2025-02-25T19:45:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Nottingham Forest versus Manchester City | Time: 2025-03-08T15:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Manchester City versus Brighton and Hove Albion | Time: 2025-03-15T15:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Manchester City versus Leicester City | Time: 2025-04-02T18:45:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Manchester United versus Manchester City | Time: 2025-04-05T14:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Manchester City versus Crystal Palace | Time: 2025-04-12T14:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Everton versus Manchester City | Time: 2025-04-19T14:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Manchester City versus Aston Villa | Time: 2025-04-26T14:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Manchester City versus Wolves | Time: 2025-05-03T14:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Southampton versus Manchester City | Time: 2025-05-10T14:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Manchester City versus Bournemouth | Time: 2025-05-18T14:00:00.0000000+00:00
Match: Fulham versus Manchester City | Time: 2025-05-25T15:00:00.0000000+00:00


Thanks a lot for your help, This method works however, unfortunately when using selenium, the chrome page opens up, is there any other way we could bypass the cloudflare without opening up the chrome page

you can use a free online proxy https://proxyium.com/ prototype which is quite helpful to bypass Cloudflare bot protection, but need to use the proxy URL with user-agent and cookie of https://proxyium.com/, btw you can use mine.

Thank you, i want to learn more about this proxyium thing, could you pls tell me how you learnt it, or the youtube video/channel that you learned it from?

Hey, I added the code to my answer, to learn about proxy I want to suggest this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-complete-guide-to-proxies-for-web-scraping/, for free proxy provider (which I used in the answer) visit https://proxyium.com/

Unfortunately, https://proxyium.com/ website is blocked in my region, i am unable to access it, is there any other method other than proxyium, sorry for the inconvenience...

to make it not open the browser, add chrome_options.add_argument('headless') at the top there

If u don't want to use selenium, I suggest this option with downloading the game calendar from this site, u need ICS lib
from ics import Calendar
import requests


url = 'https://api-prod.mancity.com/fixturecalendars/v1/DownloadCalendar?calendar=mens&lang=en'
c = Calendar(requests.get(url).text)
sorted_events = sorted(c.events, key=lambda event: event.begin)
for e in sorted_events:
    print(f"Match: '{e.name}' | Date: {e.begin.date()} | Time: {e.begin.time()}")

OUTPUT:
Match: 'Manchester City v Celtic - USA Tour 2024' | Date: 2024-07-23 | Time: 23:30:00
Match: 'Manchester City v AC Milan - USA Tour 2024' | Date: 2024-07-27 | Time: 22:00:00
Match: 'FC Barcelona v Manchester City - USA Tour 2024' | Date: 2024-07-31 | Time: 00:20:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Chelsea - USA Tour 2024' | Date: 2024-08-03 | Time: 21:30:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Manchester United - Community Shield' | Date: 2024-08-10 | Time: 14:00:00
Match: 'Chelsea v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2024-08-18 | Time: 15:30:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Ipswich Town - Premier League' | Date: 2024-08-24 | Time: 14:00:00
Match: 'West Ham United v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2024-08-31 | Time: 16:30:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Brentford - Premier League' | Date: 2024-09-14 | Time: 14:00:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Inter - Champions League' | Date: 2024-09-18 | Time: 19:00:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Arsenal - Premier League' | Date: 2024-09-22 | Time: 15:30:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Watford - EFL Cup' | Date: 2024-09-24 | Time: 18:45:00
Match: 'Newcastle United v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2024-09-28 | Time: 11:30:00
Match: 'Slovan Bratislava v Manchester City - Champions League' | Date: 2024-10-01 | Time: 19:00:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Fulham - Premier League' | Date: 2024-10-05 | Time: 14:00:00
Match: 'Wolves v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2024-10-20 | Time: 13:00:00
Match: 'Manchester City v AC Sparta Prague - Champions League' | Date: 2024-10-23 | Time: 19:00:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Southampton - Premier League' | Date: 2024-10-26 | Time: 14:00:00
Match: 'Tottenham Hotspur v Manchester City - EFL Cup' | Date: 2024-10-30 | Time: 20:15:00
Match: 'Bournemouth v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2024-11-02 | Time: 15:00:00
Match: 'Sporting CP v Manchester City - Champions League' | Date: 2024-11-05 | Time: 20:00:00
Match: 'Brighton and Hove Albion v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2024-11-09 | Time: 17:30:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Tottenham Hotspur - Premier League' | Date: 2024-11-23 | Time: 17:30:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Feyenoord - Champions League' | Date: 2024-11-26 | Time: 20:00:00
Match: 'Liverpool v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2024-12-01 | Time: 16:00:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Nottingham Forest - Premier League' | Date: 2024-12-04 | Time: 19:30:00
Match: 'Crystal Palace v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2024-12-07 | Time: 15:00:00
Match: 'Juventus v Manchester City - Champions League' | Date: 2024-12-11 | Time: 20:00:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Manchester United - Premier League' | Date: 2024-12-15 | Time: 16:30:00
Match: 'Aston Villa v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2024-12-21 | Time: 12:30:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Everton - Premier League' | Date: 2024-12-26 | Time: 12:30:00
Match: 'Leicester City v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2024-12-29 | Time: 14:30:00
Match: 'Manchester City v West Ham United - Premier League' | Date: 2025-01-04 | Time: 15:00:00
Match: 'Brentford v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2025-01-14 | Time: 19:30:00
Match: 'Ipswich Town v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2025-01-19 | Time: 16:30:00
Match: 'Paris Saint-Germain v Manchester City - Champions League' | Date: 2025-01-22 | Time: 20:00:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Chelsea - Premier League' | Date: 2025-01-25 | Time: 17:30:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Club Brugge - Champions League' | Date: 2025-01-29 | Time: 20:00:00
Match: 'Arsenal v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2025-02-01 | Time: 15:00:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Newcastle United - Premier League' | Date: 2025-02-15 | Time: 15:00:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Liverpool - Premier League' | Date: 2025-02-22 | Time: 15:00:00
Match: 'Tottenham Hotspur v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2025-02-25 | Time: 19:45:00
Match: 'Nottingham Forest v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2025-03-08 | Time: 15:00:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Brighton and Hove Albion - Premier League' | Date: 2025-03-15 | Time: 15:00:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Leicester City - Premier League' | Date: 2025-04-02 | Time: 18:45:00
Match: 'Manchester United v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2025-04-05 | Time: 14:00:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Crystal Palace - Premier League' | Date: 2025-04-12 | Time: 14:00:00
Match: 'Everton v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2025-04-19 | Time: 14:00:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Aston Villa - Premier League' | Date: 2025-04-26 | Time: 14:00:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Wolves - Premier League' | Date: 2025-05-03 | Time: 14:00:00
Match: 'Southampton v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2025-05-10 | Time: 14:00:00
Match: 'Manchester City v Bournemouth - Premier League' | Date: 2025-05-18 | Time: 14:00:00
Match: 'Fulham v Manchester City - Premier League' | Date: 2025-05-25 | Time: 15:00:00


Thank you, however is there no other way we can directly scrape from the https://www.mancity.com/ website?

@ManasSujalAbraham matches on the main page are loaded from the calendar via JS, u can use special services to render these pages or selenium. or do u have some other problem on this site?
